# Pandas Time Series: Remove Rows Per ID

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, time-series, pandas-groupby

I have a Pandas dataframe of the form:

```
Date       ID     Temp
2019/03/27 1       23
2019/04/27 2       32
2019/04/27 1       42
2019/04/28 1       41
2019/01/27 2       33
2019/08/27 2       23
```

What I need to do?

> Select Rows which are at least 30 days old from their latest measurement for each id.

i.e. the latest date for `Id = 2` is `2019/08/27`, so for `ID =2` I need to select rows which are at least 30 days older. So, the row with `2019/08/27` for `ID=2` will itself be dropped.

Similarly, the latest date for ID = 1 is `2019/04/28`. This means I can select rows for `ID =1` only if the date is less than `2019/03/28` (30 days older). So, the row `2019/04/27` with `ID=1` will be dropped.

How to do this in Pandas. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Final dataframe will be:

```
Date       ID     Temp
2019/03/27 1       23
2019/04/27 2       32
2019/01/27 2       33
```

Answer (score 5):

In your case using `groupby` + `transform('last')` and filter the original df

```
Yourdf=df[df.Date<df.groupby('ID').Date.transform('last')-pd.Timedelta('30 days')].copy()
        Date  ID  Temp
0 2019-03-27   1    23
1 2019-04-27   2    32
4 2019-01-27   2    33
```

Notice I am adding the `.copy` at the end to prevent the setting copy error.